# H2 Get row count for all tables

Tags: sql, count, h2

I would like to know the total number of rows for each table. And that for all tables at once. Is this possible with H2?

I'm thinking of a table:

```
|table name | row size |
```

At the moment I'm using the current version 1.3.170 (2012-11-30).

Comment: you want to count the total number of rows ?

Comment: Not sure in H2, but in Oracle DB, you could use `SELECT table_name, num_rows FROM user_tables`. Check if the same is available there too.

Comment: @Arpit yes the total number of for each table.

Comment: @Orangecrush: that will only give you an *estimate* of the row counts, not the real count.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would need to use a user-defined function, for example:

```
drop alias count_rows;
create alias count_rows as 
'long countRows(Connection conn, String tableName) 
    throws SQLException {
ResultSet rs = conn.createStatement().
    executeQuery("select count(*) from " + tableName);
rs.next();
return rs.getLong(1); }';
select table_name, count_rows(table_name) count 
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
where table_schema = 'PUBLIC';
```

This code doesn't take into account the schema, and only works for unquoted table names.

Comment: Works like a charm. I had issues with Java version at first, somehow I mixed up Java 6 and Java 7. Then I started it from console instead double clicking the jar file.

Comment: You can use `table_schema = SCHEMA()` to limit the call only for current schema

Answer (score 0):

Try `SELECT table_name, row_count_estimate FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES WHERE table_schema = 'PUBLIC'`. It will get you an "estimate", but chances are the results will get you the information you need.